# JavaScript / jQuery using more words instead of IndexOf - Chat Bot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question. I use a Chat Bot, i want to add more words, but it doesn't work. How can i use an Array with words?

Thanks for your help.

```
function bot(message) {
    var words = ['hello', 'hi', 'hey'];
    if(wordChecker(message, words)) {
        var messageArray = [
            'Hello to you too!',
            'I said hello first :)',
            'Greeting, human.'
        ];

        sendMessage(messageArray);
    }
    else if (wordChecker(message, words)) {
        var words = ['1', '2', '3'];
        var messageArray = [
            'Word1',
            'Word2',
            'Word3'
        ];

        sendMessage(messageArray);
    }

    else if (message.indexOf('good fine') >= 0) {

        var messageArray = [
            'Okay, so what do you want to talk about?',
            'Okay, what is your problem? Tell me.',
            'Do you have something to say? Say it. Let it out your chest.'
        ];

        sendMessage(messageArray);
    }
```

WordChecker Function:

```
function wordChecker(message, words){
    var has = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if(message.indexOf(words[i])) {
            has = true;
            }
    }
    return has;
```

}

Comment: Are you saying you want to test for more words than just `hello`? I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: @Sam - yes, you're right!

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this

Comment: Also, what do you mean? Do you want to add more items to the message array, or have a completely separate array?

Comment: I would like to add to all if else Statements a new array with words.

Comment: This new part is on you to figure out. We can't hold your hand through the entire process of building your application. You've got to try to figure some things out on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extend your code, I have added a `database` array at very start to separate your code and data part separate.

```
function bot(message) {
    var database = {
        'hello|hi|hey' : ['Hello to you too!','I said hello first :)','Greeting, human.'], //Separate with | if you want output when any one of all is match
        'mango|banan' : ['I am mango man!','I Love Mango :)','Mangoes are my favrout.'], // Another words' set
        'price' : ['What is price of your services!','What best price you can give me :)','My price is unbearable.','Can you give me down time'] // Single Varialbe
    };

    var output = [];
    for (var words in database) {
        if (database.hasOwnProperty(words)) {
            $constraint_or = words.split("|");
            for (i=0; i<$constraint_or.length; ++i)
                if(message.indexOf($constraint_or[i]) >= 0){
                    output = output.concat(database[words]);
                    break;
                }

        }
    }

    console.log(output); // For testing output
    if(output.length>0)
        sendMessage(output);

}

bot("hi hello"); // Calling for test
```

Comment: If i type 'Hello', the bot will say 3 of the words in the messageArray, but i want to say like: hello, hi or something like that. But i don't know, how to do that.

Comment: See my second solution, I have handled many cases in that one.

Comment: It works, but that is too many code, does not an other solution exists, like a Array, where i can put Words in?

Comment: Yes, I can can design something like that for you. Can you vote my solution above first if it is working for you at least :)

Comment: Done, yes please that can be very nice. :)

Comment: I will edit code and will give you solution as 3rd case. You will have an array where you have to populate all words to be matched and output strings array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function bot(message) {
    if (message.indexOf('hello') >= 0) {

        var messageArray = [
            'Hello to you too!',
            'I said hello first :)',
            'Greeting, human.'
        ];
        return messageArray;
    }
}


       console.log(bot("hello ok "));
```

You were missing a semicolon didn't you ?

Comment: No, i didn't. In this line, must be a change. But i don't know, what i have to use..
"if (message.indexOf('hello') >= 0) {"

Comment: If i type 'Hello', the bot will say 3 of the words in the messageArray, but i want to say like: hello, hi or something like that. But i don't know, how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I'm understanding correctly, but from my interpretation it sounds like you just need the "or" operator.

```
 if (message.indexOf('hello') >= 0 || message.indexOf('hi') >= 0 || message.indexOf('sup') >= 0) { 
    // Other logic
 }
```

EDIT:

Using a function instead:

```
// First argument is you message
// Second argument is your array of words
function wordChecker(message, words){
    var has = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if(message.indexOf(words[i])) {
            has = true;
        }
    }
    return has;
}
```

Then with that function you could just do:

```
var words = ['hello', 'hi', 'hey'];
if(wordChecker(message, words)) {
    // other logic here
}
```

Comment: Yes you're Right, i'm come from Russia, thats the reason why i speak not so well english. It works, but that is too many code, does not an other solution exists, like a Array, where i can put Words in?

Comment: A better way of doing it would be with a function. I'll add something to my post.

Comment: Your solution is very nice, but one Problem exists. There is too many ifelse Statements, and if you make one "var words", than for only all. I send you the code, look on the top, i edited it.

Comment: The `words` argument in `wordChecker` can accept any array. It doesn't have to specifically be the `words` array that's already created. Just make a different array with a different name like `var moreWords = ['hola', 'gracias', 'bueno']` and pass it into the other `wordChecker` function: `wordChecker(message, moreWords)`.

Comment: I don't understand how can i do that? I've tried some ways, but it seems to not work. Can you give me an example please?